# getting error semicolon found on line number 20

Tags: batch

```
public class AUditingBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
public String query;

public Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<AUditTrial__c> scope)
    {
    List<AUditTrial__c> InsrtRecord = new List<AUditTrial__c>(); 
    AUditTrial__c AU=new AUditTrial__c();
    AU.Section__c='Custom Objects';
    AU.Action__c='deletedApexClass';
    AU.name='Rakeshsingh';
    AU.Display__c='Changed Location page layo';
    AU.add(InsrtRecord);

    insert InsrtRecord;

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
  AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
  from AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =:BC.getJobId()];
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
   mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
   mail.setSubject('Apex Sharing Recalculation ' + a.Status);
   mail.setPlainTextBody
   ('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
   ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
   Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

Comment: Question must be well researched before posting on Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to write end parenthesis, should be:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<AUditTrial__c> scope)
{
    List<AUditTrial__c> InsrtRecord = new List<AUditTrial__c>(); 
    AUditTrial__c AU=new AUditTrial__c();
    AU.Section__c='Custom Objects';
    AU.Action__c='deletedApexClass';
    AU.name='Rakeshsingh';
    AU.Display__c='Changed Location page layo';
    AU.add(InsrtRecord);

    insert InsrtRecord;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey You forgot to write end parenthesis, so code is like :

```
public class AUditingBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
public String query;

public Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<AUditTrial__c> scope)
    {
    List<AUditTrial__c> InsrtRecord = new List<AUditTrial__c>(); 
    AUditTrial__c AU=new AUditTrial__c();
    AU.Section__c='Custom Objects';
    AU.Action__c='deletedApexClass';
    AU.name='Rakeshsingh';
    AU.Display__c='Changed Location page layo';
    AU.add(InsrtRecord);

    insert InsrtRecord;
}
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
  AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
  from AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =:BC.getJobId()];
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
   mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
   mail.setSubject('Apex Sharing Recalculation ' + a.Status);
   mail.setPlainTextBody
   ('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
   ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
   Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis is missing after `insert InsrtRecord;`.